# Import/export module in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
import { hello } from './hello';

hello();
```

**hello.js**

```
export function hello() {
  console.log('Hello!');
}
```

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module app.js:1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add type to the script tag:

```
<script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: This is a solution with the following remarks:  1) add .js extension to import statement - `import { hello } from './hello.js';` and 2) run through a server, for example Live Server extension for VSCode. Thank you!

Comment: MDN example: https://github.com/mdn/js-examples/tree/master/modules/basic-modules